# Data not fetch on where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm facing a problem while applying case..when in where clause in sql. when I  put value between 0 and 4 in where clause I get the expected result but when apply case, it fails.

Table name: myTbl

> ```
> data | amount |    date      | ReceiptFrequency
>
>   A     2000     02-03-1988     Annual
>   A     2000     02-03-1990     Semiannual
>   A     2000     02-03-1991     Annual
>   A     2000     02-03-1992     Annual
> ```

```
create TABLE #Table ( num int NOT NULL, );

;WITH Nbrs ( n ) AS (
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 + n FROM Nbrs WHERE n < 60 )
  INSERT #Table(num)
  SELECT n FROM Nbrs
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 60 )

 SELECT *FROM #Table AS x,#Table AS y,myTbl AS d
    WHERE (d.ReceiptFrequency<>'Random') AND(x.num BETWEEN 0 AND 1(CASE WHEN d.ReceiptFrequency='Annual' THEN 1 WHEN d.ReceiptFrequency='Quarter' THEN 1 WHEN d.ReceiptFrequency='Month' THEN 12 WHEN d.ReceiptFrequency='SemiAnnual' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END -1))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on *it will not get better result*? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your expected result would be very helpful.

Comment: If ReceiptFrequency is Month then 12, If ReceiptFrequency is Semi-Annual then 2, if ReceiptFrequency is Annual then 1, So shouldnt  you use 4 for ReceiptFrequency Quarter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why **-1**  at the end of your CASE..WHEN?

```
CASE WHEN d.ReceiptFrequency='Annual' THEN 1 WHEN d.ReceiptFrequency='Quarter' THEN 1 WHEN d.ReceiptFrequency='Month' THEN 12 WHEN d.ReceiptFrequency='SemiAnnual' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END -1))
```